# Declare a variable without type

Tags: ios, swift, class, variables, skscene

I am making a game and I have different game modes. These game modes are in separate classes. When the user picks a game mode, the respective class is used in the code. However, for the manipulation of any game mode I have used scene. Is there a way to use one variable or do I have to use multiple?

Here is the ViewController that deals with the game modes:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

let classic = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
let timed = Timed(fileNamed: "Timed")
let endless = Endless(fileNamed: "Endless")
var scene: SKScene?

init() {
    if (gameMode == "Classic"){
        var scene = classic
        print("Classic")
    }
    else if (gameMode == "Timed"){
        var scene = timed
        print("Timed")

    }
    else if (gameMode == "Endless"){
        var scene = endless
        print("Endless")

    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let yourVC = segue.destination as? Postgame {
        yourVC.score = scene!.score
    }
}
```

Comment: you should drop the `var` in front of the `scene` assignments in `init`. Now regarding your actual question: do the three variables have a common super type like `SKScene`?

Comment: looks like you should be using an enum: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically speaking, you can go with:

```
var score: Any!
```

`Any` means anything, any type.

Other than that, it seems that you're looking for (and basically talking about) a Strategy design pattern. It seems to be the right way to solve your task.
In short: define a protocol, implement it by all your strategies, use the one you need, call methods by protocol-unified names.

Have a read: [Strategy Design Pattern in Swift](https://medium.com/design-patterns-in-swift/design-patterns-in-swift-strategy-pattern-1d11945b4adc)

Comment: How exactly does "Strategy Design Pattern" differ from just saying "use a Swift protocol"?  This "Design Pattern" is literally just an interface.

Comment: You can say "use a Swift protocol" if you wish. And by doing that, leave plenty of room to misconception. Design patterns (even Strategy, one of the simpler of them) are much more than just an "interface". It's a pattern, which implies particular context and particular type of a task. When you discover more patterns (and I believe you will eventually), it will get easier to communicate with fellow professionals. By mentioning `Strategy`, the approach is much more clear than by saying "use a Swift protocol", for the latter would require of you to elaborate a lot.

Comment: Hexfire: I've been using "Design Patterns" since the GoF book was first published.  You're doing a lot of hand-waving, without explaining what exactly "misconception" might occur, or what "particular context" this fancy name has.  The Wikipedia article, for example, says that in this context, "an algorithm is a piece of code that does something appropriate" -- I'm not sure how it could be more vague.  Your link merely says Strategy implementations are "interchangeable", which is essentially the definition of an interface.

Comment: You are taking it too personal. I believe there's nothing worth the argument. I did explain it fairly straight-forward, without any 'hand-waving' as you call it. I will point it out again for you: by saying `Strategy` (or any other pattern) the context of the task is clear. To the contrary, you can "*explain*" your solution, by saying: "Make few classes, define a protocol, implement that protocol for each class, create some managing class capable of 'switching' between these classes and call that method".

Comment: And that's essentially the same (actually not, because a lot might miss) as just saying "use Strategy". When you know pattern (read: common approach of solving tasks of particular type), you know the context. You don't need to elaborate. Contrarily, you would *need* to elaborate when you proposition sounds as just "use a Swift protocol". Does this make sense now?

Answer (score -1):

A Swift variable has to have a type.  Otherwise, how would the compiler know what you can do with it?

In this case, it apparently has a `score` property, so you should make a protocol with that:

```
protocol GameMode {
    var score: Int { get }
    // and whatever else is common to these classes
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. Variable can be defined with `Any` type. It should, however, be cast to a particular type in order to properly obtain its value.

Comment: Which part is not correct?  As you note, `Any` *is* a type: the Swift reference manual calls it a "special type".  And this does tell the compiler what you can do with it: cast it (and not much else!).

Comment: Semantically speaking, `Any` can contain anything, that's why – if one pursues the goal of assigning `anything` to a var – it can well meet the definition for a variable without, well, a (particular) type. Having said that, you don't always have to be formal when answering questions. It's more about semantics and practice.